# How do I get the value of input tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Why do I get a empty string `""` when I try to get the value of my input field instead of the number I gave.When I type `billAmount` in the console window,I get `""` returned.Why is that?

```js
var billAmount = document.getElementById('bill-id').value;
```

```html
<html>
<input type="number" id = "bill-id" class="bill-input" placeholder="0">
</html>
```

Comment: When do you try to get the value? If your code runs before you put your value in the input field it wont have your value, and variables do not auto update

Comment: placeholder is not a value use value="0" to get value, Also put js below html if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only executes once.

If you want to update the variable everytime the user changes the value of the input, listen for the `input` event:

```js
var billAmount;
document.getElementById("bill-id").addEventListener('input', function(){
  billAmount = this.value;
  console.log(billAmount);
})
```

```html
<html>
<input type="number" id = "bill-id" class="bill-input" placeholder="0">
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your webpage loads the input element in the DOM. Then, the javascripts starts running. It rapidly collects the input's value which is empty. Presuming the only line of JS is `var billAmount = document.getElementById('bill-id').value;`, it finishes its jobs. Your JS doesn't detect any change of the input's value. You should add an event listener and change the variable each time you enter something.